# preg_match not functioning with pattern

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to search through html tags with PHP and I cannot seem to get the regex correct, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. 
Here is the pattern I am trying to search through:

```
<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas='somesite.edu'>
<cas:authenticationSuccess>
<cas:user>user29</cas:user>
</cas:authenticationSuccess>
</cas:serviceResponse>
```

I used $resp = htmlentities(file_get_contents($url)); and the above prints out if I echo $resp. 
I am trying to use preg_match to search in cas:user to extract the username , user29.

Here is the regex pattern I am trying to use:

```
preg_match("'<cas:user>(.*?)</cas:user>'", $resp, $match);
```

But it doesn't seem to work when I echo $match[1]. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (If the question _were_ about Python, I would say that it's suspicious that the first argument has both quote marks and apostrophes. But for all I know maybe that's just how php works, so I won't say anything.)

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: See here: https://ideone.com/1auScb

Comment: `$match` is an array, so `echo $match;` won't work. Use `print_r()` or `var_dump()`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try parsing XML with regular expressions. Instead use a DOM parser like so:

```
$xml = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas='somesite.edu'>
    <cas:authenticationSuccess>
        <cas:user>user29</cas:user>
    </cas:authenticationSuccess>
</cas:serviceResponse>
XML;

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$node = $xpath->query("//cas:user");
if ($node->length) {
    echo $node[0]->textContent;
}
```

This could be done with less code in a flat XML document, but namespaces complicate things a bit and make it easier to use XPath.

Answer (score 1):

You're parsing XML with regex which is not the best option. However if you MUST use regular expressions try this:

```
preg_match("/<cas:user>(.*?)<\/cas:user>/", $resp, $match);
```

**EDIT**

You code works, try `echo $match[1];`. Thanks to @Barmar.

Comment: You need delimiters around the regexp.

Comment: In fact, the quotes that he used were being used as the delimiters. His code works.

Comment: You're right, edited now :) Edit again: you're right again. Didn't try it but it actually works.

Comment: `echo $match[1];` is probably what he really wants.

Comment: I have also tried $match[1] and it doesn't work. Will edit my question